# How to scroll two-columns buttons in Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I can include six buttons and displays correctly as [image: aPlus99].

Now I want to include more than six buttons in scrollable view, but I can't handle it for matching available space, creating 2 rows (or columns if portrait).

Can you provide some way to achieve this?

**References:**

I have a composed button created using the following code:

```
public class ImageButtonText extends RelativeLayout {    
    ImageButton button;
    TextView label;    
    Holder holder;

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        li.inflate(R.layout.big_button, this, true);

        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);

        /*initialise button and label*/
    }
}
```

and the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/component_margin">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/text_box"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/component_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

finally add to the main layout using:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButtonText
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        custom:buttonBackground="@drawable/states_green"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_safe_call"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn1_info"
        android:text="@string/btn1text"
        android:textColor="@color/text_green" />

    <ImageButtonText
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        custom:buttonBackground="@drawable/states_red"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_private_call"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn2_info"
        android:text="@string/btn2text"
        android:textColor="@color/text_red" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTES**

May be a different approach also. My final goal is to display multiple buttons (each containing a stretched image and bottom aligned text) in two rows if portrait or three columns if landscape. All this wrapped in scrollable view.

**UPDATE:**
I solved using RecyclerView :D Thanks everyone

Comment: You could use OnDraw Method to calculate height and width. I will try to post something later when i have time

Comment: I'll be waiting for you @Leandro. May be a diferent approach also. My final goal is to display multiple buttons (each containing expanded image and bottom aligned text) in two rows if portrait or three columns if landscape. All this wrapped in scrollable view. I added this as clarification.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question entirely. Why not use a TableLayout wrapped inside a horizontal scroll view? Is your view dynamic or static?

Comment: i wrote an approach, i hope i understood right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and dynamic approach would be to create a custom List of buttons and put it into a GridView with 2 Colums resp. Rows.

This adapter i did for my navigation has an icon and a text, maybe it helps you. The icon is on the Left side as you can read in this line: holder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.get_icon(), 0, 0, 0); Te second one would be the icon above text.

Anyway, I think you will need a custom layout, wich you can easily create doing a new xml file with a Relative or LinearLayout and put an ImageView and a TextView into it and give as a parameter in constructor layoutResourceId.

The height of a listItem you can define in this layout xml file.

The GridView you can Configure different for Landscape and Portrait

- In landscape mode the layout from the layout-land/ will be used
- In portrait mode the layout from the layout-port/ will be used

  ```
  public class NavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavItem> {

  List<NavItem> data;
  Context context;
  int layoutResourceId;

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View row = convertView;
      NavHolder holder;

      if(row == null)
      {
          LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
          row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

          holder = new NavHolder();

          holder.textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

          row.setTag(holder);
      }
      else
      {
          holder = (NavHolder) row.getTag();
      }

      NavItem item = data.get(position);
      holder.textView.setText(item.get_title());
      holder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.get_icon(), 0, 0, 0);
      //holder.textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);

      return row;
  }

  public NavigationAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<NavItem> data) {
      super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
      this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
      this.context = context;
      this.data = data;
  }

  static class NavHolder
  {
      TextView textView;
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: I going to test this solution late night

Comment: Good luck! If you have problems, tell me.

Comment: Since no more solutions provided, I accept yours. Thank you